# Make ar­ray data struc­tures in LaTeX

Tags: macros, data-structures

Is there a way to make an array in LaTeX.
I want to write a function that does this (here the array has only 2 elements but I want to be able to have many as I want).

```
\foo{\MakeArray{foo,bar}}
```

> foo|bar-foo&bar

I could have done this like that

```
\newcommand\foo[2]{\1-\2}
\foo{foo|bar}{foo&bar}
```

But I need to enter the elements twice which is not very neat...

**EDIT:**
Sadly, even if your answer solve my question, it doesn't work with my exact case so I'll tell it exactly.
I currently have

```
\newcommand{\authors}[2][e ]{
  \usepackage[pdfauthor={#1}]{hyperref}
  \author{#2}
}
```

that I use that way

```
\authors{John Doe, Dark Vador and Yoda}{John Doe \and Dark Vador \and Yoda}
```

and I would like to have the same result without specifying it twice.
However, the `\and` doesn't work with the proposed solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It would be helpful to know exactly what you want to accomplish. There is [the `arrayjobx` pacakge](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/arrayjobx), but I tend to just use comma separated lists, and use pgf's `\foreach` to process them. `newcommand{\fooArray}{foo,bar}` should suffice.

Comment: I have told exactly what I want to do now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Load the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) first, and then set the PDF document properties using `\hypersetup`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\newcommand{\authors}[1]{
  {\renewcommand{\and}{\unskip, }\hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}}
  \author{#1}
}
\title{My title}
\authors{John Doe \and Dark Vador \and Yoda}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Inside `\authors`, the definition of `\and` is momentarily updated to insert commas.

Answer (score 10):

For the special case, there is also a cheap solution. `\and` can be redfined for `hyperref`'s `pdfauthor`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\and{, }} 

\newcommand*{\authors}[1]{%   
  \hypersetup{pdfauthor={#1}}%
  \author{#1}%
}
\title{Test document}
\authors{John Doe\and Dark Vador\and Yoda}% without space before \and
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And `pdfinfo` reports:

```
Author:         John Doe, Dark Vador, Yoda
```

Answer (score 5):

The real application is almost trivial with `xparse` and `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\authors}{O{,}m}
 {
  \legat_authors:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\seq_new:N \g_legat_authors_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \legat_authors:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_gset_split:Nnn \g_legat_authors_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \hypersetup {pdfauthor={ \seq_use:Nn \g_legat_authors_seq { , } } }
   }
  \author{ \seq_use:Nn \g_legat_authors_seq { \and } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\authors{John Doe, Dark Vador, Yoda}
\title{Star Wears}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The only subtle point is passing the list of authors expanded to `\hypersetup`, which is obtained by `\use:x`.

The command `\authors` has an optional argument; if a different delimiter than a comma is needed one can set it in the optional argument:

```
\authors[;]{Dean Martin; Sammy Davis, Jr; Jerry Lewis}
```

Note that this requires an up-to-date TeX distribution.

[image]

How does it work? The `\seq_gset_split:Nnn` function (globally) stores the third argument as elements of the sequence, using the second argument as delimiter between items. This sequence can then be used as many times as one wants. Here we use it first for passing the comma separated list of authors to `\hypersetup`, then as the argument to `\author`.

Comment: Your solution is great, sadly, I'm looking for a simple solution that works through many LaTeX version :)

Answer (score 2):

Since I couldn't get yours to give any output, I changed some definitions around to produce parsed output of the form you requested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}

\renewcommand\and{\textbf{AND}}
\newcommand\MYusepackage[2][1]{[#1]\{#2\}\par}
\newcommand\MYauthor[1]{#1}

\newcommand\authors[1]{%
  \MYusepackage[pdfauthor={#1}]{hyperref}%
  \encodetoken{\and}
  \convertword[e]{#1}{~and~}{, }%
  \convertchar[e]{\thestring}{,}{ \and}%
  \retokenize{\thestring}%
  \MYauthor{\thestring}%
  \decodetoken{\and}%
}
\begin{document}
\authors{John Doe, Dark Vador and Yoda}
\end{document}
```

[image]